# Can't connect Hibernate to JavaFx application.Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, jdbc

```
@FXML
protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
sessionFactory = new Configuration()
.configure("configuration/hibernate.cfg.xml")
.addAnnotatedClass(Movie.class)
.addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
.buildSessionFactory();
 ...
```

This is my code.I have this error message, when try to create SessionFactory:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2554)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2529)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.4.11.Final/org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:28)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.4.11.Final/org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:24)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.4.11.Final/org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:85)
at com.example.rating/com.example.rating.Main.onHelloButtonClick(Main.java:21)
... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
... 68 more
```

[This is project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEbkr.png)
[File Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTQxX.png)

Comment: no images of plain text, please - simple c&p is the tool you want to use for code and stacktrace/error messages ;)

Comment: I am not allowed to put picture yet, but you can see them with the link.Please, help me

Comment: you mis-understood me: you __must not__ show plain text as images ..

Comment: I'm sorry.I didn't know

Comment: hmm .. this doesn't look related to javafx - can you connect in a plain java context, that is no ui?

Comment: Yes, i do and it works.But when i try to do this in JavaFx i can't even create SessionFactory

Comment: okay, then compare your setup for the plain java context with your fx context: it should be the same except that javafx modules are added .. wild guessing, of cause, setup issues are hard to debug :)

Comment: Does your `module-info.java` contain `requires java.sql`?

Comment: Mark Rotteveel, you made my day.Thank you so much, you were helpful!